Table content is shown faded on next page
I am trying to generate a PDF using itextpdf. When the table is extended to the next page, the color is shown faded. Suppose I have generated four pages of PDF, then on the first and fourth page it's fine, but on the second and third page the table content color is shown faded.
It's very weird, please help me in this.
Below is the code:
public class PdfGenerator {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        ClassPathResource templateResource = new ClassPathResource("RandomTemplate.pdf");
        File pdfFile = new File(templateResource.getFile().getAbsolutePath());

        CustomEventHandler eventHandler = null;

        try (PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(pdfFile);
        ) {
            ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            PdfWriter pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(outputStream);
            PdfDocument targetDocument = new PdfDocument(pdfReader, pdfWriter);

            PdfReader pdfReader2 = new PdfReader(pdfFile);
            PdfDocument sourceDocument = new PdfDocument(pdfReader2);

            eventHandler = new CustomEventHandler(sourceDocument);
            targetDocument.addEventHandler(PdfDocumentEvent.END_PAGE, eventHandler);

            Document document = new Document(targetDocument);
            document.setMargins(95, 24, 100, 24);

            sourceDocument.copyPagesTo(1, 1, targetDocument);

            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                Table table = new Table(4);

                table.addHeaderCell(new Cell(1, 4).add(new Paragraph("Random Header Title")).setBold().setPaddingLeft(5).setBorderLeft(new SolidBorder(3)));
                table.addHeaderCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("RANDOM DATE")).setBold().setPaddingLeft(5).setBorderRight(Border.NO_BORDER).setBorderLeft(Border.NO_BORDER).setBorderBottom(Border.NO_BORDER));
                table.addHeaderCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("RANDOM MEASUREMENT")).setBold().setPaddingLeft(5).setBorderRight(Border.NO_BORDER).setBorderLeft(Border.NO_BORDER).setBorderBottom(Border.NO_BORDER));
                table.addHeaderCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("RANDOM PERCENTILE")).setBold().setPaddingLeft(5).setBorderRight(Border.NO_BORDER).setBorderLeft(Border.NO_BORDER).setBorderBottom(Border.NO_BORDER)).setFontSize(7);
                table.addHeaderCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("RANDOM SCORE")).setBold().setPaddingLeft(5).setBorderRight(Border.NO_BORDER).setBorderLeft(Border.NO_BORDER).setBorderBottom(Border.NO_BORDER));

                for (int j = 0; j < 50; j++) {
                    table.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("dd/mm/yyyy")).setPaddingLeft(5).setBorderRight(Border.NO_BORDER).setBorderLeft(Border.NO_BORDER).setBorderTop(Border.NO_BORDER));
                    table.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph(String.valueOf(j + 1))).setPaddingLeft(5).setBorderRight(Border.NO_BORDER).setBorderLeft(Border.NO_BORDER).setBorderTop(Border.NO_BORDER));
                    table.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("#.#%")).setPaddingLeft(5).setBorderRight(Border.NO_BORDER).setBorderLeft(Border.NO_BORDER).setBorderTop(Border.NO_BORDER)).setFontSize(8);
                    table.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("#.##")).setPaddingLeft(5).setBorderRight(Border.NO_BORDER).setBorderLeft(Border.NO_BORDER).setBorderTop(Border.NO_BORDER));
                }

                table.setBorder(new SolidBorder(1));
                table.setWidth(767);
                table.setMarginTop(20);
                document.add(table);

            }

            targetDocument.removeEventHandler(PdfDocumentEvent.END_PAGE, eventHandler);
            document.close();
            targetDocument.close();

            byte[] finalPdfBytes = outputStream.toByteArray();

            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream("FinalRandomOutput.pdf");
            fileOutputStream.write(finalPdfBytes);
            fileOutputStream.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    static class CustomEventHandler implements IEventHandler {
        private final PdfDocument sourceDocument;

        public CustomEventHandler(PdfDocument sourceDocument) {
            this.sourceDocument = sourceDocument;
        }

        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event event) {
            System.out.println("Event Triggered");
            PdfDocumentEvent documentEvent = (PdfDocumentEvent) event;
            PdfDocument pdfDocument = documentEvent.getDocument();
            PdfPage originalPage = sourceDocument.getPage(1);
            pdfDocument.addPage(originalPage.copyTo(pdfDocument));
        }
    }
}

I want use one PDF template, it has only one page, so I need to duplicate the page, but the event listener was not duplicating to second page, so the first time I manually copy the page and then after that event listener works fine.
Why is the content shown faded? I don't understand this.

So do I need to set default colors for PDF or for that table ?

It seems to be an issue because you are using setBold method.
This is a hacky implementation to provide of setting bold text without the need for specialized font's.
The approach you could try to see if it resolves it is: https://kb.itextpdf.com/itext/how-can-i-use-regular-and-bold-in-a-single-string

Hi, Thanks for your reply but for headerCell I can understand, but what about normal cell, there I am not using any setBold() method.

Also, I removed that setBold() from everywhere, but still same issue persists.
